# getAttachmentsAsync() does not return AttachmentDetailsCompose in callback for inline attachments

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an outlook add-in that gets attachment details and sends them to the server for heavy lifting. But I am facing an issue with processing inline attachments. `mailItem.getAttachmentsAsync()` is not returning attachment details for inline attachments on Google chrome. It is working fine on safari and Outlook native clients.

If I am using eventType `AttachmentsChanged`. It returns an "Attached" event for newly added inline attachments though.

Is this an issue or am I missing something here?

Comment: Where and when do you call the `getAttachmentsAsync` method?

Comment: In messagecompose taskpane add-in, I fetch all the attachments from compose pane and process them before sending mail from the back-end.